# Laravel use query result in a controller

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I have a problem with laravel
I want to use a query result in my controller with a if clause to manage what i return to the view.

```
 $res = Chaussures::where('id',$id);
 if($res->name=='Adidas'){
     return...
 }
 else {
     return...
 }
```

I tried this but it didn't work

Comment: why not try `return Chaussures::where('id',$id)->first()->name == 'Adidas' ? 'something' : 'something_else';`

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute the query to get the result first. Then you can do whatever you need with the data.

```
$res=Chaussures::where('id',$id)->first();
```

Searching for models by ID is such a common task that Laravel has a method called `find()` to make it easier. This line does the same as the above.

```
$res=Chaussures::find($id);
```

Comment: The problem is that i cant realy use $res

Comment: You can't use `$res` because it's a query builder instance, not a model with data. If you updated your code with my answer then you should be able to use `$res` as expected.

Comment: I have to use where on a column which is not the primary so your answer didn't work

Comment: @user8078820 You need to provide more code otherwise we're just guessing how to solve your problem.

Comment: @user8078820 I answered based on the information provided. If this does not solve it you need to provide more information. My first example will fix your problem as asked, and the second one is just more info for when you are searching by the primary column.